# Removing automatic inline style

Tags: jquery, html, css, inline-styles

I'm trying to have a table row hide until a radio button is clicked. I've tried `display:none;` but that didn't work. So when I checked out the code in my developer tools I saw that the tr has a `style="display: table-row;` which I never added and none of the other tr has it.

I'm not sure on how to remove it so that I can hide that row.

My code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("value") == "collection") {
      $(".deliver-fee").hide('slow');
    }
    if ($(this).attr("value") == "delivery") {
      $(".deliver-fee").show('slow');
    }
  });
  $('input[type="radio"]').trigger('click');
});
```

```css
.deliver-fee {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="delivery-option">
  <div class="form-check">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="delivery-option" id="delivery" value="delivery">
    <label for="delivery" class="form-check-label">
    Delivery
   </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-check">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="delivery-option" id="collection" value="collection">
    <label for="collection" class="form-check-label">
    Collection
   </label>
  </div>
</div>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Product</th>
      <th scope="col">Code</th>
      <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
      <th scope="col">Unit Price</th>
      <th scope="col">Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4">
        <div class="float-right">
          Sub Total
        </div>
      </th>
      <td>R{{ $totalPrice }}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="deliver-fee">
      <th colspan="4">
        <div class="float-right">
          Delivery Fee
        </div>
      </th>
      <td>R{{ $delivery }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So what is supposed to happen is the `.delivery-fee` row is hidden automatically when the page has loaded and once the user has clicked on delivery then the `.delivery-fee` row is shown.

Comment: Do you have any external CSS loading up? If this is the only 'deliver-fee' on the page, you may want to use an ID, rather than a class and set the display in that.

Comment: I tried your code and it is working.

Comment: I've tried what everyone here suggested, but it isn't working. I think it is because `style="display: table-row;` is being added automatically to my `<tr>` and I can't seem to remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the item hide at the beginning via the css - this works perfectly.

But then you show it with:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').trigger('click');
```

the reason the delivery fee app appears briefly and then hides is because the above code runs *twice* (as you have 2x `input[type='radio']`) - first time for delivery, so calls `.show()` then for collection so calls `hide`.

jQuery queues animations, which includes .hide and .show.  You could use `.finish()`, as in

```
  $(".deliver-fee").finish().hide('slow');
```

but this would just hide the issue.

The easiest option is to just remove that line and wait for user to click.  If you need the delivery fee shown based on preloaded info, then only run it for the `:checked` item

```
$('input[type="radio"]:checked').trigger('click');
```

Updated snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("value") == "collection") {
      $(".deliver-fee").hide('slow');
    }
    if ($(this).attr("value") == "delivery") {
      $(".deliver-fee").show('slow');
    }
  });
  // Don't show+hide delivery fee
  //$('input[type="radio"]').trigger('click');
});
```

```css
.deliver-fee {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="delivery-option">
  <div class="form-check">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="delivery-option" id="delivery" value="delivery">
    <label for="delivery" class="form-check-label">
        Delivery
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-check">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="delivery-option" id="collection" value="collection">
    <label for="collection" class="form-check-label">
        Collection
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Product</th>
      <th scope="col">Code</th>
      <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
      <th scope="col">Unit Price</th>
      <th scope="col">Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4">
        <div class="float-right">
          Sub Total
        </div>
      </th>
      <td>R{{ $totalPrice }}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="deliver-fee">
      <th colspan="4">
        <div class="float-right">
          Delivery Fee
        </div>
      </th>
      <td>R{{ $delivery }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Regarding `display:table-row` - this is a red herring.  jQuery is clever enough to see that you are calling `.show()` against a table row, so rather than add `display:block` it adds `display:table-row`.

This there because your js code calls `.show()` on that `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct but now I only remove `css` which you add and now its working.. check below code:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="collection"){
                $(".deliver-fee").hide('slow');
            }

            if($(this).attr("value")=="delivery"){
                $(".deliver-fee").show('slow');

            }        
        });

        $('input[type="radio"]').trigger('click');
    });
```

```html
<div class="delivery-option">
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="delivery-option" id="delivery" value="delivery">
        <label for="delivery" class="form-check-label">
            Delivery
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="delivery-option" id="collection" value="collection">
        <label for="collection" class="form-check-label">
            Collection
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Product</th>
      <th scope="col">Code</th>
      <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
      <th scope="col">Unit Price</th>
      <th scope="col">Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4">
        <div class="float-right">
            Sub Total       
        </div>
      </th>
      <td>R{{ $totalPrice }}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="deliver-fee">
      <th colspan="4">
        <div class="float-right">
            Delivery Fee
        </div>
      </th>
      <td>R{{ $delivery }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.js"></script>
```